# Can Oracle 12.2 Client communicates with Oracle.DataAccess.dll with 11.2 version?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

Our application is built and packaged with oracle 11g Oracle.DataAccess.dll and in the same box we have installed 12.2 Oracle Client (No other oracle client is installed). The Oracle server is running on 12.2 version.

Now, when we are installing our product, it is trying to communicate to Oracle Server via the client. But the Oracle.DataAccess.dll of our product (which is basically 11g version) is not able to communicate to 12.2 Oracle Client.

Is there a way we can communicate successfully? We don't want to package the 12.2 dll with our installer and release it immediately. Please suggest if there is any tweak which can make it compatible.

Thanks,
Arindam.

Comment: Do you mean you have version 12.2 and 11.2 installed on one machine? This could be challenging because some components rely on `%PATH%` environment variable which means "first come - first served"

Comment: No. I have 12.2 oracle client installed. But my application is .NET based application and it is packaged with 11.2 Oracle.DataAccess.dll. So this dll will communicate with 12.2 client to update the oracle server.

Comment: Then see my answer, on your machine it should be automatically redirected to your 12.2 version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Comment: But how the 11.2 dll from my product and the present 12.2 oracle data access dll will communicate? Do I need to modify anything to make it work? I have this config file: Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess.config

Comment: Again, your product **does not** load the 11.2 dll - it loads the 12.2 version (if installed, of course)

Comment: So, are you saying that we need to modify the Oracle.DataAccess.config file? Or 12.2 Oracle.DataAccess.dll should be packaged?

Comment: If Oracle is properly installed you don't have to put any Oracle.DataAccess.dll to your application package. You can set "Copy local = False"

Comment: See, we can't do much with our product/application now. It is already released. I am looking for some registry changes or config tweak which can help me to communicate 11g dll with 12c oracle client.

Comment: That is not possible, as I wrote in my answer version of Oracle Client and version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll has to be the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173211/discussion-between-wernfried-domscheit-and-arindam-mukherjee).

Answer (score 0):

No, version of Oracle Client and version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` have to match. You may face problems even if the minor versions are different, e.g. Client Version `12.1.0.2.x` vs. `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` version `12.1.0.1.x`.

But it should be no problem, provided the ODP.NET (i.e. `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`) is installed with Oracle Client. The GAC should include Policies like

```
Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess.config ->

<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89B483F429C47342"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.112.0.0-4.112.9999.9999" newVersion="4.122.1.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

It does not matter whether your application was build with ODP.NET version 11.2, the policy should redirect it to installed version 12.2 automatically.

Otherwise go to one of these pages

- [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)
- [32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) and NuGet Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html)

and download the matching **XCopy** version. Extract correct `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` file from ZIP and provide it together with your application.